# Vim key mapping in UltraEdit

Tags: vim, ultraedit

Does anybody know how to enable VIM key mapping in UltraEdit ?
Default UE key mappings are for windows, emacs, etc., but not VIM. 
Googling for easy ways to do it or some template file yielded zero results.

Thanks,
Evgeni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is no way to enable any other "mode" of key mappings in UltraEdit (i.e. no way to change over to another set of keymappings within the app such as make it use emacs or vim key mappings).

Having said that, UltreEdit offers you a *a lot* of ways to customise your keymappings. Here is a good overview: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/keymapping.html. AFAIK You can change every single keymapping. Once you have customised your keymappings to your liking, you can also back up the keymapping file and use it in other installations (the location of the keymapping file is outlined in the overview).

One very cool feature that will help you create a custom key mapping is: Advanced > Configuration > Key Mapping > click Show key mapping in editor. This will generate a text file with all your current key mappings.

Beyond key mappings, you can also create macros and assign keyboard shortcuts to them.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I've been using SlickEdit for my personal projects; it has all those features. At work they purchased UltraEdit.

Comment: I tried very hard to adapt a Star Wars quote to this situation and failed. So imagine that this quote very wittily invokes images of your journey towards loving UltraEdit. :) The Emperor: You want this, don't you? The hate is swelling in you now. Take your Jedi weapon. Use it. I am unarmed. Strike me down with it. Give in to your anger. With each passing moment you make yourself more my servant.

Comment: When I saw this topic, I leaped in, hoping I would learn something spectacular involving my 2 very favorite editors, Vim and UltraEdit. Alas, disappointed again.